# Generating 1000 random numbers between 13 and 100

Tags: java, random

I'm trying to generate 1000 random numbers between 13 and 100. So far it's only generating 75% of what I want repeatedly a thousand times. Here's what I have so far:

```
Random rand = new Random();
for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
{
    int pick = rand.nextInt((87) + 13);
    pick++;
}
```

Why isn't it working?

Comment: `rand.nextInt((87)+13)` is the same as `rand.nextInt(100)`...

Comment: something looks strange abot this code `nextInt((87)+13)`

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean to do `rand.nextInt(87) + 13`?

Comment: just noticed that Cody thank you, no it didn't change anything

Comment: also note that nextInt gives even distribution, nextGaussian uses normal distribution. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution

Answer (score 4):

Pay attention to `nextInt()` covering the 0 **inclusively** and the specified value **exclusively**! So it has to be `rand.nextInt(88)` to make the highest `int` generated be 87. Here is what you want:

```
Random rand = new Random();
for (int j = 0; j<1000; j++)
{
    int pick = rand.nextInt(88)+13;
}
```

Comment: @ZouZou yeah, sorry, my mistake. But all the other solution random(87)+13 will not cover the 100, right?!

Comment: Yep, you need to call `nextInt(88)`.

Comment: But if you are doing that, you need to remove `pick++;`. ;)

Answer (score 1):

`rand.nextInt(88) + 13;` should give you numbers between 13 and 100, and you just put it in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

The line :

> So far its only generating 75% of what i want repeatedly a thousand times

Really doesn't add up to me. It might be a seeding issue you're having though. Make sure to always re-seed the random number, using time.

But I agree with Abdul , you need to take the `+13` out of that parenthesis:

```
rand.nextInt(87) + 13;
```

Because  `rand.nextInt((87) + 13)` is the same as `rand.nextInt((67) + 23)` as `rand.nextInt((1) + 99)`

But if you want more "true" randomness, look into something called buzzhash (though that is for hashing ; yet may be modded for number)

Comment: took the 13 out of the parenthesis and nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

I use this in my codes:

```
public static int randomInteger(int min, int max)
{
    java.security.SecureRandom rand = new java.security.SecureRandom();

    //get bounded [0, max) from nextInt()
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt(max) + min;

    return randomNum;
}

value = randomInteger(13,100); //13..99
value = randomInteger(13,101); //13..100
```